# Multi-sized image grid (bootstrap) for Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I want to make a multi-sized boostrap grid to my wordpress blog, where the featured images have different width and height size, like this [Tumblr theme](http://disassemble3theme.tumblr.com/).

Any ideas / tips ?

Answer (score 0):

I've used [salvattore](http://salvattore.com/) [ Not a wordpress plugin ] with bootstrap 3 and worked very well and as for the wordpress version, it won't be too difficult to implement.

There's a good tutorial on how to use **salvattore** with bootstrap on this [LINK](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-dynamic-grid-with-salvattore-and-bootstrap-in-10-minutes--cms-20410)

---

If you are looking for some easy solutions then i would recommend these two wordpress plugins ( and are many more to choose from )

[First Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-masonry-layout/) - *Some premium features*

[Second Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/photoswipe-masonry/screenshots/)

[Third Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-masonry-gallery/)

Comment: Thanks! But isn't this with fixed (the same) wdith and not different width of the image ?

Comment: I added another plugin since the first plugin had some premium features ( Perhaps the one you are after ).

The width depend on the image, Some plugins do give a choice for a fixed width or the one like you mentioned in Pinterest.

Yet again, If you are familiar with wordpress development, You will be able to easily add the **salvattore** plugin and have a pinterest like image grid.

Comment: Dont forget to select it as answer if it helps, Just below the vote sign, You will find a tick sign such as in this [Image](http://pasteboard.co/ZNmuQBX.png), It will be green once you click on it.